# Insufficient Privilieges - Sys Admin - Every Link

Tags: administration

Created a new user with standard profile System Administrator. Irrespective of the link I click in system, even Personal Settings and My Profile and even searching anything gives the same insufficient privileges message:

> Error: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation
>   you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your
>   administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see
>   Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this user has the `API Only` permission assigned to it. If you can access records via something like workbench that would definitely be the issue.

See also [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=User-Permission-for-API-Integration-User&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1) for further info on this permission.

Comment: While this seems like a valid point, if using the **standard** system admin user profile as the OP says, it is **not possible** for it to be an API only user as you cannot edit the profile

Comment: Checked and confirmed not a API only user.